# Importing text file into mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to import data from a txt. file into mysql. The only problem is where do i save the text file for it to be read into the database.

I know this is a terribly stupid question. Im sorry, couldn't find an answer online.

I will be using the following line of code

```
load data infile 'player_data.txt' into table Player"
```

So where do i save the player_data.txt?

Answer (score 1):

You can import text file in two ways:

1. Place file on server with running MySQL and call:

   `LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/file.txt' INTO TABLE table;`

   File must be located on the server host and is read directly by the server. If path is not specified,  the server looks for the file in the database directory of the default database.
2. Import file from any directory on local host:

   `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:\path\file.txt' INTO TABLE table;`

You can also specify fields termination, lines termination and ignore few first lines.
For more options see [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)